# Finding free non-intersecting rectangle shaped areas between rectangles in C#

Tags: c#

I have a following problem. A large rectangle contains smaller non-intersecting rectangles (The black rectangles in the picture below) and I need to find an algorithm to fill remaining free area with non-intersecting rectangles(red ones in the picture below). Speed is not an issue for the algorithm. Also if someone would have an example source code of the algorithm I would really appreciate that.

Edit. Small clarification I need to get the coordinates of the red rectangles not to draw them. I am also working with point data not images.

http://koti.mbnet.fi/niempi2/Squares.gif

Comment: Do you start from point data or an image?

Comment: Point data, meaning coordinates of the black rectangles in the picture. I also need to get the coordinates of the red rectangles not just draw them.

Comment: There is more than one way to define a set of red rectangles for a given set of black rectangles.  Do you care which set is returned?

Comment: Only thing that matters is that smallest possible number of filling rectangles is returned. The layout does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most bin-packing problems this one looks like an NP-hard problem to me.  With 2 rectangles, there are 8! (= 40320) possible arrangements you need to consider.  Three rectangles produces 12! possibilities, a cool 480 million.

You'll need an heuristic to make this computable.  Beyond favoring the outer edges of the rectangles closest to the bounding rectangle, I don't see a good one.  You'd need tighter requirements on the resulting rectangles you accept, the number of them isn't going to help.  Glad this is not my problem :)

Comment: As I said before the layout of the rectangles does not matter and actually I can drop the requirement of having smallest possible number of filling rectangles. So really I don't have to go through every possible solution because I can simply pick the first one that fills all the empty space. The solution I was thinking was to first calculate the 4 outermost filling rectangles which is a easy task and after that calculate the center rectangles separately in this case you would only have 4! possible arrangements with 2 rectangles.

Comment: @Nobugz: Can you please tell me how you calculated 2 rectangle would require 8! and 3 would require 12!?

Comment: @Joan: generate all possible combinations of rectangle edges.  You've got 8 to choose from when placing the first rectangle.  Then 7 for the next.  Etc.  8 x 7 x .. x 1 = 8!  12 edges for 3 rectangles.

Comment: Yes I knew how to calculate the 4 outermost filling rectangles but I still need to calculate the inner rectangles to which I was asking help to.

Comment: Make a list of rectangles.  Compute a new rectangle by initializing it from the edge to the outer bounds, trim it with the bounds of the ones in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are multiple possible solutions, I think you can get to one fairly easily.

I would work in increasing values along one axis.  By scanning all rectangles and ordering their edge's appearances along that axis, you could walk through them and create rectangles as you go.  Each time you hit a new pair of corners, you can compare with the rectangles you currently have 'open' and determine what to do (close them, start new, divide, etc).

That statement isn't a complete solution, but I think it gets you from a complex solution to a simple one.  It also doesn't seem to be NP complete in terms of performance.  You might even be able to get O(n) perf.

An interesting problem.  Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Region class.

Comment: please stop calling people names without any reason or provocation when retagging their questions. Especially when the mis-tagging is down to a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59556/tags-with-uppercase-characters-get-cut)